# Center fixed image horizontally to the top without taking space

Tags: html, css, image

I need my 2000x2000px image to be centered horizontally to the webpage. From there I want the center of the image to hug the top of the page. Lastly I do not want the image to take up space on the page, but I still want it visible. Below is an image I made to visualize what I want.

[image]

Comment: Based on what you wrote, it seems that the top of the image will never be seen.  Please clarify.

Comment: Something like this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f9u20y3p/)?

Comment: @MarcAudet correct, this is a very specific image I want to use. It is basically a rotating set of rays if you were curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/117/

**HTML**

```
<div class="div">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.div {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.div img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  left: calc((400px - 300px) /-2); 
}
```

First value in `calc` should be `width` of your picture and second should be `width` of your parent `div`

Answer (score 0):

If your code is

```
<div class="img-container">
    <img></img>
<div>
```

Modify your css as:

```
img.container{ 
    overflow:hidden;
}

img.container img{
    margin-top:-200px;
    width:100%;
}
```

You can adjust the margin to your liking.